# Subset command is not working as the State column entry is not found in R language

Tags: r

I am using the given csv: https://data.incovid19.org/csv/latest/states.csv

My task is to subset the statedf data frame (which is basically the above csv loaded into a data frame) into mystatedf data frame such that it contains data of only the state Rajasthan. Here is my attempt:

```
statedf <- read.csv("states.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
names(statedf) = c("Date", "State", "Confirmed", "Recovered", "Deceased", "Other", "Tested")
mystatedf=subset(statedf,State==Rajasthan)
mystatedf
```

However, it shows the following error in my Posit Cloud R Markdown:

```
Quitting from lines 438-442 [unnamed-chunk-29] (HW_2.Rmd)
Error:
! object 'Rajasthan' not found
Backtrace:
 1. base::subset(statedf, State == Rajasthan)
 2. base::subset.data.frame(statedf, State == Rajasthan)
 3. base::eval(e, x, parent.frame())
 4. base::eval(e, x, parent.frame())
Execution halted
```

Comment: Try: "mystatedf=subset(statedf,State=="Rajasthan")"

Comment: The fact that it allegedly works locally but not deployed suggests that you have an object in your local workspace named `Rajasthan` that might contain the literal string you're looking for. Or something completely different. The only way `subset(statedf, State == Rajasthan)` can work with this data is if there is an object named that ... otherwise it is either a typo or a misunderstanding of R's `subset` command.

Answer (score 1):

You just missed the `"` here
Please change

```
mystatedf=subset(statedf,State==Rajasthan)
```

to

```
mystatedf <- subset(statedf, State == "Rajasthan")
```

It should be work. Here is my attempt and sample output
[image]